# RedisRequestLogger not working

Tags: logging, service, servicestack

I had added the RequestLogger to my service code to enable logging. It worked fine

```
    Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());
```

Now I replaced it with the RedisRequestLogger. Now the logging doesnt work.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong that RedisRequestLogger isnt working

```
          Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature
        {
            RequestLogger = new RedisRequestLogger(
                container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>(), capacity: 1000)
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to snake case I was using in the code
I added the following JsConfig.PropertyConvention = PropertyConvention.Lenient;to AppHost.cs and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The `RedisRequestLogger` needs a `IRedisClientsManager` configured, e.g:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new RedisManagerPool(redisConnectionString));
```

Where `redisConnectionString` is a [Redis connection string](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings) to an accessible master **redis-server**.

Which will then work after registering `RequestLogsFeature` Plugin once, i,e:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature {
    RequestLogger = new RedisRequestLogger(
        container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>(), capacity: 1000)
});
```

If you're not seeing any Request logging at `/requestlogs` then check [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) for any Startup Errors. If there aren't any use the **redis-cli.exe** to connect to the same Redis Master configured above (from the same server hosting the Web Application) and check if it connects and if the `log:requests` Sorted Set has been created and populated.

Comment: I do have it registered in AppHost.cs file -    

private void RegiesterIOC(Container container)

        { 
          
            container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["redis"].ToString()));
            
        }

The logging shows but the data is all messed up - like dates appear as 0:00:00 Z ....etc so not sure what needs to be done to fix it

Comment: I used the redis desktop manager and log:requests show sorted set created and populated but the http://localhost:XX/requestlogs still shows default values not the exact get and post values